# Iterating through objects of arrays in vanilla JS with a forEach

Tags: javascript

```
const users = {terry1: [{action: "unpaid", user: "terry1", member: true}, {action: "paid", user: "terry1", member: true}], malcomla3: [{action: "paid", user: "malcomla3", member: true}], jonny:[{action: "paid", user: "jonny", member: true}]}
```

I have data that looks like like the above.  Each key represents a username and that array(s) that is associated with it is another object(s) with relevant fields to that user, ex: `{action: "paid", user: "doug101", member: true}`

I'm trying to run a loop to go through each user key and see if they have any value of `unpaid` for the `action` but I'm stuck on how to proceed with the code below to do that.

```
 for (var key in users) {
     users[key].forEach(x => {

     })

  }
```

Comment: Can you post the *actual full* data of `users` (not just `Array(2)`)?

Comment: Have you tried: `if (x.action === "unpaid") console.log(x.user);` inside your `forEach` function block?

Comment: You are showing examples of the properties being arrays, but your description (i.e. `{action: "paid", user: "doug101", member: true}`) suggests they are objects. Which is it? Or are they arrays *of* objects.

Comment: `const users = {terry1: [{action: "unpaid", user: "terry1", member: true}, {action: "paid", user: "terry1", member: true}], malcomla3: [{action: "paid", user: "malcomla3", member: true}], jonny:[{action: "paid", user: "jonny", member: true}]}`

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, arrays of objects...I just edited the question above.  Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish the code you started, using `forEach`, here is how-to, using `.hasOwnProperty()` to check if the object in the array is `action`, and if it is, is it "unpaid".

*Note, based on a comment I increased one of the users object array's with a third item.*

Stack snippet

```js
const users = {
  terry1:    [
               {action: "paid", user: "terry1", member: true},
               {action: "unpaid", user: "terry1", member: true},
               {action: "paid", user: "terry1", member: true}
             ],
  malcomla3: [
               {action: "paid", user: "malcomla3", member: true}
             ],
  jonny:     [
               {action: "paid", user: "jonny", member: true}
             ]
}


for (var key in users) {
  users[key].forEach( function(item) {
    for (var key2 in item) {
      if( item.hasOwnProperty("action") && item[key2] == "unpaid" ) {
         console.log(key, 'not paid')
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: OP's structure differs a bit from this. He does not have a separate object for each property, but rather an array of objects, each with properties `user`, `action`, and `member`.

Comment: @TylerRoper OP just commented at another answer (and their question) showing this exact object structure.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. OP does not show the `action`, `user`, and `member` properties in separate objects (unless they've done some edit-fu between the time of your answer and my comment).

Comment: @TylerRoper Updated

Comment: thanks @LGSon ...what is the `for (var key2 in item)` portion doing here?

Comment: @user10108817 For the same reason you iterate your `users` object _terry1/malcomla3/jonny_, you need to with the _action/user/member_ object. Makes sense?

Comment: @LGSon yep but what if *terry1*, for example, has 3 arrays of objects belonging to it.  So there are 3 objects of *action/user/member*.  Let's say I need to make sure all the values of *member* is `paid`.  How can I compare them to each other just for that user?

Comment: @user10108817 It does that already. "terry1" has 2 such objects, and as one of them is "unpaid", it finds that.

Comment: @user10108817 I updated my answer and added a 3rd object for "terry1", in the middle, and it stills finds it.

Comment: thanks so much @LGSon ...helps me understand it a lot more now

Comment: @user10108817 Great...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the array and get all `unpaid` objects in array, iterate through the keys and filter the objects that have action as `unpaid`

```
for (k in users) { users[k] = users[k].filter(function(obj) { return obj.action === 'unpaid';}) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the entries from the object, search for the key you want, and then either use that array, or reconstruct it into an object as follows:

```js
const users = {
  terry: [{action: "paid"}, {cool: false}],
  alice: [{action: "unpaid"}]
};
const unpaid = Object.entries(users).filter(([name, fields]) => fields.find(field => field.action === "unpaid"));

const unpaid_as_object = Object.assign(...unpaid.map(([k,v]) => ({[k]: v})));
console.log(unpaid_as_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're really set on using `forEach` then this snippet should work

```js
const users = {terry1: [{action: "unpaid", user: "terry1", member: true}, {action: "paid", user: "terry1", member: true}], malcomla3: [{action: "paid", user: "malcomla3", member: true}], jonny:[{action: "paid", user: "jonny", member: true}]};

for (var key in users) {
  users[key].forEach(user => {
    if (user.hasOwnProperty("action") && user.action === "unpaid") {
      console.log(user.user + " is unpaid")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: it's an array of objects, so it'd look like this : `terry1: [{action: "paid"}, {action: "unpaid"]`,